# "ERROR in Unexpected token (314:202513)" without any further information

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to build a hybrid project with `yarn` then `yarn build`, however I get an error with only `ERROR in Unexpected token (314:202513)`. It doesn't include which file causes the error. Anyone can shed some light on how I can further investigate the error?

Some other information:

- the command executed which causes the error seems to be `node --max_old_space_size=8192 .electron-kungfu/build.js && electron-builder` in `app` sub-folder of the project.
- the js part of project uses typescript, vue, webpack
- some other outputs around the error:

```
 |     [365] ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/notification.js 16.3 KiB {2} [built]
 |     [366] ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/message-box.js 32.4 KiB {2} [built]
 |     [505] ./src/renderer/main.js + 320 modules 434 KiB {2} [built]
 |           | ./src/renderer/main.js 8.04 KiB [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/notification.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/base.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/message-box.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/checkbox.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/tooltip.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/loading.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/form-item.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/form.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/radio-group.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/radio.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/dialog.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/popover.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/switch.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           | ../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/dropdown-menu.css 50 bytes [built]
 |           |     + 306 hidden modules
 |         + 1011 hidden modules
 |
 |     ERROR in Unexpected token (314:202513)
 |     Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
 |                               Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
 |         __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  7.49 KiB       0  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
 |         Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
 |         [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.ejs 3.9 KiB {0} [built]
 |     Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!src/renderer/assets/iconfont/iconfont.css:
 |                               Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
 |         imgs/iconfont--iconfont.svg  10.9 KiB
 |         Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
 |         [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js 830 bytes {0} [built]
 |         [1] ./src/renderer/assets/iconfont/iconfont.eot?t=1558590944328 5.04 KiB {0} [built]
 |         [2] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 1.57 KiB {0} [built]
 |         [3] ./src/renderer/assets/iconfont/iconfont.woff?t=1558590944328 3.3 KiB {0} [built]
 |         [4] ./src/renderer/assets/iconfont/iconfont.ttf?t=1558590944328 4.8 KiB {0} [built]
 |         [5] ./src/renderer/assets/iconfont/iconfont.svg?t=1558590944328 71 bytes {0} [built]
```

Sorry I have very little experience on frontend so the question may not be quite clear, please comment for any clarification.

Also I want to know if there is any commandline arguments which can force `yarn` or `node` to printout more information?

Any help is highly appreciated!!!